# Does using -- anywhere inside an HTML Comment make the Comment invalid HTML?

Tags: html, validation, comments, specifications

`View Source` in **Firefox 78.0.1**  is suggesting to me that if I use `--` inside a multi-line HTML comment, it renders the comment invalid HTML.

That is:

```
<!-- 

  multiline

  comment

  here

-->
```

is valid, but this:

```
<!-- 

  -- multiline

  -- comment

  -- here

-->
```

is not.

Is this right?

I've searched Stack Overflow and the web and I'm unable to find authoritative confirmation of the requirement that an `<!-- HTML comment -->` **must not** contain `--` anywhere apart from the very beginning and the very end.

---

**Added:**

I note that **Chrome 83** does not have a problem with it.

Is it possible that **Firefox 78** is mis-flagging a false positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is because Firefox 78 uses the W3C validator, which has a parsing error when searching for errors in comments. So, it is just misflagging false positives. I assume that this will probably be fixed at some point but, for now, I would suggest either ignoring it or using a different browser, as Firefox is the only one I can find which automatically uses the W3C.

Comment: It definitely works. So no problem there. But View Source in Firefox 78.0.1 is suggesting that it's invalid. This is what I'm trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: I ran mine on Firefox 78 and it appears to work as well. I'm not sure what the error could be.

Comment: Thanks - I have found the error now. I think that it is because Firefox 78 uses the W3C validator, which has a parsing error when searching for errors in comments. To answer your earlier question - yes I think that it is misflagging false positives. I assume that this will probably be fixed at some point but, for now, I would suggest either ignoring it or using a different browser, as Firefox is the only one I can find which automatically uses the W3C.

Comment: That's great - thanks very much, @Lilwen. If you can copy-paste your comment immediately above into your answer, I will accept. Thank you, again!

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to pretty much exactly what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Many thanks, @Lilwen - I appreciate your research and confirmation that it's the Firefox 78 HTML parser which is in error, rather than it being the case that including the substring `--` inside an `<!-- HTML Comment -->` is an invalid practice.